# How to test java code that uses Basho's riak-java-client?

Tags: java, unit-testing, riak

I'm creating a small java service that returns a list of restaurants depending on the selected place.
Data is retrieved from Riak using com.basho.riak:riak-client:2.0.0 and the read operation is wrapped in a TenacityCommand.

Important classes are described below and I would be happy if you could assist me in creating a solid and simple unit test.

Commands are created using a factory:

```
package service.command.factory;

import com.basho.riak.client.api.RiakClient;
import com.basho.riak.client.api.commands.kv.FetchValue;
import com.basho.riak.client.core.query.Location;
import com.basho.riak.client.core.query.Namespace;

import domain.Place;
import service.command.FetchRestaurantsCommand;

public class FetchRestaurantsCommandFactory {

    private final RiakClient riakClient;
    private final Namespace namespace;

    public FetchRestaurantsCommandFactory(final RiakClient riakClient, final Namespace namespace) {
        this.riakClient = riakClient;
        this.namespace = namespace;
    }

    public FetchRestaurantsCommand create(final Place place) {
        Location location = new Location(namespace, place.getName());
        FetchValue riakCommand = new FetchValue.Builder(location).build();
        return new FetchRestaurantsCommand(riakClient, riakCommand);
    }
}
```

And the command looks like this:

```
package service.command;

import java.util.Optional;

import service.command.keys.WhereToEatDependencyKeys;

import com.basho.riak.client.api.RiakClient;
import com.basho.riak.client.api.commands.kv.FetchValue;
import com.basho.riak.client.api.commands.kv.FetchValue.Response;
import com.yammer.tenacity.core.TenacityCommand;

import domain.Restaurant;
import domain.RestaurantList;

public class FetchRestaurantsCommand extends TenacityCommand<Optional<RestaurantList>>{

    private final RiakClient riakClient;
    private final FetchValue fetchValue; 

    public FetchRestaurantsCommand(RiakClient riakClient, FetchValue fetchValue) {
        super(WhereToEatDependencyKeys.RIAK_GET_RESTAURANTS);
        this.fetchValue = fetchValue;
        this.riakClient = riakClient;
    }

    @Override
    protected Optional<RestaurantList> run() throws Exception {
        Response response = riakClient.execute(fetchValue);
        return Optional.ofNullable(response.getValue(RestaurantList.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected Optional<RestaurantList> getFallback() {
        return Optional.of(RestaurantList.createFallback(new Restaurant("My failure suggestion")));
    }

}
```

The above classes are used like:

```
Place place = // Created from url parameter
RiakClient riakClient = // created on start using the app's conf
Namespace namespace = // created on start using the app's conf

FetchRestaurantsCommandFactory factory = new FetchRestaurantsCommandFactory(riakClient, namespace);
FetchRestaurantsCommand command = factory.create(place);
return command.execute();
```

Apart from the features provided by `TenacityCommand`, how should I assert that my system fetches data as expeceted?

My initial idea was to mock a `RiakClient` to return a predefined `FetchValue.Response` and then make assertions on the resulting `RestaurantList`.
Unfortunately its not possible to instantiate or `Mockito.mock` a `FetchValue.Response` due to its design.

The accepted answer in [How to mock riak java client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442495/how-to-mock-riak-java-client) describes why Mockito won't work.

Comment: Did you look at the how the riak developers unit test theirs own classes ? May be it could help ? https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/tree/develop/src/test/java/com/basho/riak/client/api/commands

Comment: Good thinking! Unfortunately their FetchValue test looks like this:   // TODO: Do something with this. You can't mock the responses because the parents aren't public  
  
    @Ignore 
    public class FetchValueTest

Comment: :( may be some integration tests could be a way. https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/tree/develop/src/test/java/com/basho/riak/client/api/commands/itest

Comment: Another option could be to give a try to powermock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PowerMock as suggested by @gontard. See my unit test on GitHub: [FetchRestaurantsCommandTest.java](https://github.com/martensjostrand/WhereToEatBackend/blob/f715348d2981665ba565729bbfbc48b3161fd038/src/test/java/service/command/FetchRestaurantsCommandTest.java)

I considered to create a fake/mock RiakClient in the com.basho.riak.client package. Such class could hopefully instantiate the Response object in the same way as the real client does. It would probably work for fetchValue but it would grow too big when involving more advanced Riak concepts s.a. siblings.

Answer (score 1):

As far a I understood you want to write unit test. So you want to test that assuming some `Response` whether `Optional<RestaurantList>` instance is constructed correctly or not. 
What I can think of is to wrap `riakClient.execute(fetchValue);` in a protected (or package private) helper function like:

```
Response fetch() {
  return riakClient.execute(fetchValue);
}
```

Then in your test you can inherit from `FetchRestaurantsCommand` and override `fetch` function by returning any `Response`

Now, you can write any test to see whether the conversion of given `Response` to `Optional<RestaurantList>` behaves as expected or not.

If you need entire code and my explanation is not clear enough let me know to provide it.

Comment: The problem is that it's not possible to instantiate the Response object. the class that overrides fetch() have no way to create it's return value. If I understand correctly your solution would work perfectly if it was the  FetchValue that was hard to create.